# Why wrapping into a function is required in .change() of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why this works in jQuery :

```
$('#selCars').change(function(){
     alert( "I have changed!" );
})
```

but not this one :

```
$('#selCars').change(alert( "I have changed!" ) );
```

Comment: This is not about jQuery. You should learn the basics of Javascript first, get a good book. I don't want to insult you.

Comment: Or have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: @bazmegakapa: You are right on your critics; I should have thought about it a bit before jumping on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, what you wrote actually IS insulting. Why can the owner of the accepted answer can choose to help where he could also give a reply like yours? If you intend to help people, then do so.. Otherwise pleaso remain silent.

Comment: @Emin I intended to help. I really mean that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass a function reference to `.change()`. Your second example just has code there, not a function reference.

Your first example works because it passes a function reference which IS what is required.

A function reference is required because this is a callback that will be called at a later time.  The `.change()` function which executes immediately needs to save the callback reference into it's own variable and then call it later when the change event actually occurs.  To do that, it needs a function to call at that later time, not a raw piece of code.

And, the other answer is because, `.change()` was written to require a function reference.  That's how the developers that spec'ed and wrote it designed it.  If you want it to work, you have to follow their rules.

Comment: But maybe the question is, "why do I pass a function reference instead of just call a function directly". ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, which is far more informative and educative than a insult intended person. Sharing such knowledge actually does show us (the beginners) the right path.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29), i.e. you're passing something that be called back later, so what you've to pass is a reference to a function, and **that reference will be stored and called when the event will fire**.

The change method doesn't store some code, it stores only a pointer to the function. Your function is called an **event handler**.

Answer (score 1):

It's because [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) attaches an event handler to an element. The handler won't be called until the event has occurred.

Since in JavaScript, functions are just another datatype, you could also do this:

```js
var handler = function(event) {
    alert("I have changed!");
}
$('#selCars').change(handler);
```

Note that `handler` is a function, Whereas alert() would just return `undefined`.